# Getting 401 Unauthorized Error - MS Graph/PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Trying to get the hang of MS Graph in PowerShell. Have set up the application registration in Azure, and can connect to Graph just fine.

However, once I try to query the Graph API, I get a 401 unauthorized error. For the below example, I've added all possible Device/Devicemanagement permissions to the Azure Application API permissions. See code below:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$Device
)

#Check if the module is installed
$GraphInstalled = Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name "Microsoft.Graph"
If (!$GraphInstalled) {
    Write-Host "Microsoft Graph module not found." -f Yellow
    Write-Host "Installing Microsoft Graph module. . ." -f Yellow
    Install-Module -Name "Microsoft.Graph" -Repository "PSGallery" -Force -AllowClobber
}

Write-Host "Connecting to MS Graph. . ." -f Yellow
$AppID = 'x'
$TenantID = 'x'
$Certificate = 'x'
Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $AppID -TenantID $TenantID -CertificateThumbprint $Certificate


function Get-AzureADDevice {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$Name
    )

    $GraphVersion = "v1.0"
    $Header = @{

    Authorization = "$($Request.token_type) $($Request.access_token)"
    }
    
    try {

        $Resource = "Devices/?`$filter=devicename eq '$Device'"
        $Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/$GraphVersion/$($Resource)"

        (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers $Header -Method Get).Value

    }
    catch{

        Write-Host "An error occurred:"
        Write-Host "$_"

    }


}

Get-AzureADDevice -Name $Device
```

Comment: Where is the $request parameter declared or filled with the access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tested on our environment and getting same 401-unauthorised issue, We found that we don't need to add any external function for it ,Instead of that we can use [**`Get-MgDevice`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/get-mgdevice?view=graph-powershell-1.0)

Below script that we used:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$Device
)

#Check if the module is installed
$GraphInstalled = Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name "Microsoft.Graph"
If (!$GraphInstalled) {
    Write-Host "Microsoft Graph module not found." -f Yellow
    Write-Host "Installing Microsoft Graph module. . ." -f Yellow
    Install-Module -Name "Microsoft.Graph" -Repository "PSGallery" -Force -AllowClobber
}

Write-Host "Connecting to MS Graph. . ." -f Yellow
$AppID = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
$TenantID = 'xxxxxxxxx'
$Certificate = 'xxxxxxxxx'
Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $AppID -TenantID $TenantID -CertificateThumbprint $Certificate
Get-MgDevice -Filter "displayName eq '$Device'"
```

Output details for reference:
[image]

[image]